# salt-cp error/timeout copying files

Tags: salt-stack

files are there, but when I run salt-cp to collect'em I get this funky error with no clear message. FWIW, I'm using different ports than the default:

```
publish_port: 44505
ret_port: 44506
```

...Files in place and server responding normally:

```
salt 'test1' cmd.run 'ls /tmp/test*'
test1:
    /tmp/test1-1.json
    /tmp/test1-2.json
    /tmp/test1-3.json
```

...
 Wonder what's wrong with that (also tried /tmp/test/ as dest):

```
salt-cp 'test1' /tmp/test* salt:// -l debug

[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /etc/salt/master
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /etc/salt/master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /root/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/etc/salt/pki/master', 'XXX_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:44506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new IPCClient for path: /var/run/salt/master/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] SaltReqTimeoutError, retrying. (1/3)
[DEBUG   ] SaltReqTimeoutError, retrying. (2/3)
[DEBUG   ] SaltReqTimeoutError, retrying. (3/3)
[ERROR   ] An un-handled exception was caught by salt's global exception handler:
SaltClientError: Salt request timed out. The master is not responding. If this error persists after verifying the master is up, worker_threads may need to be increased.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/salt-cp", line 10, in <module>
    salt_cp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/scripts.py", line 359, in salt_cp
    client.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/cp.py", line 38, in run
    cp_.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/cli/cp.py", line 105, in run
    ret = local.cmd(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/client/__init__.py", line 568, in cmd
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/client/__init__.py", line 317, in run_job
    raise SaltClientError(general_exception)
SaltClientError: Salt request timed out. The master is not responding. If this error persists after verifying the master is up, worker_threads may need to be increased.
salt.exceptions.SaltClientError: Salt request timed out. The master is not responding. If this error persists after verifying the master is up, worker_threads may need to be increased.
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

gosh dern it. From docs: *Salt copy is only intended for use with small files (< 100KB). If you need to copy large files out to minions please use the cp.get_file function.*

Sure... only < 100BK files.. very useful!

Comment: added **file_recv: True** to master config and used **salt $i cp.push $j upload_path=$j remove_source=True* to build a script for collecting files. Just hope this is safe enough.

Comment: May I ask why you want to copy files from your minions to your master? If security matters there might exist other approaches. By enabling the `file_recv` feature you make your master eventually vulnerable from within any connected minion. And if someone controls your master, you have a __very big problem, as the attacker gains root access to every connected minion__. We usually collect data from the minions initiated by the salt master and use the scheduler/cron (master) together with grains/modules (minions). Salt mine might also be an option when it comes to _real time data_.

Comment: It might also be an option to send your data to another service - e.g. elasticsearch for logfiles. Which option to pick heavily depends on the data you want to transfer and your whole environment. Do you control the network? How many minions are connected to the master?